# Regex expression not working in objective c

Tags: objective-c, regex

```
//string
NSString *haystack = @".test {test:test} .test2{dasf:asdF}";
//pattern
 NSString *needle = @"[^{}]*{[^{}]*}";
```

What I want from this is .test {test:test} and .test2{dasf:asdF} in an array (rest of the code handles this) but for some reason this regexp is not working correctly because no results are found.

If

```
NSString *needle = @"[^{}]*";
```

I get the following

```
(
".test ",
"",
"test:test",
"",
" .test2",
"",
"dasf:asdF",
"",
""
)
```

which is expected. After a lot of fiddling it seems to be a problem with { and } in the regex but I can't think why.

Incidently, if anyone can explain why I get these empty elements in the array above that would be useful to know as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you try using:

```
 NSString *needle = @"[^{}]*\{[^{}]*\}";
```

indeed, `{` and `}` have special meaning in regexs (but they are sort of "automatically" escaped when used within `[]`)

Comment: Hmm.. no luck, don't think } requires escaping. It throughs up this :

    warning: unknown escape sequence '\}'. Thanks anyway!

Comment: what about: NSString *needle = @"[^{}]+[{][^{}]+[}]";

Comment: Yes!! Thanks! Now why on earth does it need that? [] around {}'s? Is it a way of escaping without \?

Comment: well, I don't know what are you using to match the regex (and it could be a fault in that library), but it is sure that `{}` are modifiers, so you cannot use them freely; on the other hand `[]` have the property of escaping their content, so it does the trick. The problem is why `\{` and `\}` are rejected... that's why I think of a problem with the regex engine...

Comment: I'm using NSRegularExpression which is in the cocoa framework I think - I haven't used any external libraries.... Interesting I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [^{}]+ (with plus) instead of [^{}]*? Just because * matches also zero chars

Comment: Ah nice! answers my ancillary question at the end.. any ideas for my main problem? Thanks.

Comment: Well, because {} are special chars in regex - you specify quantity of matches with them. So a{17} means "a" 17 times. You just need to escape them, i.e. [^{}]+\{[^{}]+\}